# Find certain letters in a word

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I have searched for this for a while, and I can't seem to find anyone else whom already asked this question. If so their question might have been phrased in another way :)

So I'm building a Twitter bot that is to retweets tweets that has certain letters in a word. ie. when a goal is scored in a football match they make a tweet like "GOAAAAAAAAAAL". What I want is to filter out all the AAAA's so it just becomes "GOAL".

Any ideas?

Comment: use regexs. `/GOA+L/i` will match your case.

Comment: You have to be careful with this approach. There are many words where consecutively occurring alphabets are commonplace, and replacing them will be an issue, e.g. `Aaron` -> `Aron`, `Occurring` -> `Ocuring`. That will be bad. You probably need to compare against a known dictionary of all words instead of doing simple regex-based replacement blindly.

Comment: He seems to be searching for specific key words, he can easily write 1 regex per word, it's not a general case.

Comment: I assume he gave an example by a specific word - "GOAL".

Answer (score -1):

with code clean and case sensitive replacement

```
$data     = 'Shoot and .... GOAAAAL';
$pattern  = '/GOA(.*)L/i';
$replace  = 'GOAL';

$replaceValue = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $data);
```